# Javascript get object values from corresponding to a list of keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

Hypothetically if we have an object like:

```
data = {
    a: 3,
    b: 7,
    c: 94,
    d: 854
}
```

How could I get the values corresponding to a array of keys using vanilla javascript or jQuery? So Something similar to:

```
var keys = ["a", "d"]
Object.values(data)[keys]
```

So the output would be an array with the values [3, 854]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use map

```js
const data = {
    a: 3,
    b: 7,
    c: 94,
    d: 854
}

var keys = ["a", "d"]

const result = keys.map(rec => data[rec])

console.log(result)
```